# Error in Processing Request Error code: 502 Error text: Bad Gateway

Tags: mysql

I have a giant MYSQL database (60gb+).  I am trying to run this SQL query on it:

```
DELETE FROM ParseBanks_main where date = '2010-09-30';
```

and after about 5 minutes I get this result:

```
Error in Processing Request
Error code: 502
Error text: Bad Gateway
```

My database has 4gb RAM

Comment: Your server process is issuing an http errorcode of `502` which means you need to check your installation, it's not about your query. This doesn't even make it to mysql.

Comment: @AxelAmthor: I wouldn’t be so sure about that – if the request did not even make it to the database, then why would there by a five minute delay before this error occurs? My guess would be that this somehow runs into a timeout or memory limit after those 5 minutes … and while a `502` response code might not be the most appropriate response to such an error, we don’t know what components are involved, so we can’t say for sure what’s going on. (We don’t even know how that query is send to the database, so also not even how HTTP is involved here in the first place – more details needed, I think.)

Comment: Agreed. It _might_ be related to the query causing the mysql server to not respond properly. In a first step I would check with an `explain` how many rows are involved and whether the server in general responds to any query.